# Wordpress CodeHighlighter

Tags: plugins

I've noticed on a couple of websites that the code highlighter can have some options like print / copy to clipboard, ...

I've installed CodeHighlighter as a Wordpress plugin in my website but can't find a way to get those options.

Any help would be grateful.

Thank you

Comment: The probability is high that you won't accept an answer here.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, think I've got the wrong Plugin.
Looke like this one does the trick: SyntaxHighlighter Evolved

Olivier

Comment: Yes, the *SyntaxHighlighter Evolved* is the best plugin that uses SyntaxHighlighter for code highlighting.

Comment: Link to plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/syntaxhighlighter/